# Invalid data table format: must have at least 2 columns on google bar chart

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization, google-barchart

This chart displays information from a Database. How do I display a more user-friendly message or not draw the chart at all if there are no results retrieved from the database? I already tried placing the lines of code to draw the chart inside the length check but the error message was still displayed.

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        $.getJSON('includes/get_info_bar_chart.php', function(jsonData){

            var gglData = [];

            if(jsonData.length > 0) {
                // load column headings
                var colHead = [];
                Object.keys(jsonData[0]).forEach(function (key) {
                    colHead.push(key);
                });
                gglData.push(colHead);

                // load data rows
                jsonData.forEach(function (row) {
                    var gglRow = [];
                    Object.keys(row).forEach(function (key) {
                        gglRow.push(row[key]);
                    });
                    gglData.push(gglRow);
                });


            }

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(gglData);
            var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('d_bar'));
            chart.draw(data);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could check the number of rows in the data table before drawing the chart.
if no data, then display a message in the chart's container.

```
var container = document.getElementById('d_bar');

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(gglData);
if (data.getNumberOfRows() > 0) {
  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(container);
  chart.draw(data);
} else {
  container.innerHTML = 'No data found, nothing to see here...';
}
```